# How can I walk a JavaScript object and create a computed observable for each property?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a need to be able to create a javascript object in which all of the properties in the object are a computed observable that I have defined. For example, if I had the following object:

```
{
    prop1: 'Test prop',
    prop2: {
        innerProp1: 1,
        innerProp2: 2,
        innerProp3: 3    
    },
    [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

I want to create an object which looks like the following assuming the standard version of my observable is called revocable and the array version is called revocableArray:

```
{
    prop1: revocable('Test prop'),
    prop2: {
        innerProp1: revocable(1),
        innerProp2: revocable(2),
        innerProp3: revocable(3)    
    },
    revocableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6])
}
```

I have tried to look into the Knockout-Mapping ([Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)) fromJS  function to see if I could leverage that and tell it what kind of observable to create and it seems like it might be possible using the mapping object. The issue I see with that is I feel that I will essentially have to walk the object myself even with using fromJS in order to convert all of the object's properties into the computed observable I want. I was hoping someone had suggestions on either how to leverage KO's fromJS function in this way, or how to cleanly walk a javascript object in order to achieve this functionality. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What are these computed observables dependent on?

Comment: They are self contained. They're very similar to the protected observable found here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: Can you not write custom factory functions to transform your data to ViewModels? Are you dealing with dynamic, nested data structures? If you need all the features in the `ko.mapping` plugin, forking it and replacing the `ko.observable` and `ko.observableArray` from the source might be your best bet...

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxmj9axg/1/) an example of what you can do, not sure is what you are looking for...